# Vertical scroll inside the table

Tags: css, angular, html-table, angular-material

I am working on an Angular application which has a mat-table. I'd like to make the table scrollable with sticky headers. But, the scrollbar seems to appear outside the table.

I have tried using a container with height and overflow properties, but couldn't succeed in placing the scrollbar inside the table. Same result with npm packages like [ngx-scrollbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-scrollbar) and [perfect-scrollbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-perfect-scrollbar).

Is there a way to set the scrollbar inside the table using pure css?

[Mat-table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LNAL.png)

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz-starters-e2ugui.stackblitz.io

Edit:

app.component.html

```html
<div class="my-table">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
      The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>No.</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.position }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.name }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Weight</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.weight }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Symbol</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.symbol }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr
      mat-header-row
      *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"
      style="#A8ACAA"
    ></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

app.component.css

```css
.my-table{
  height:400px;
   overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It involves a lot of changes using `flexbox` and I cannot guarantee it's the best solution for all scenarios, but you can achieve it using `display:flex` on the table and setting `overflow-y: scroll` on the `tbody` of the table.

css

```
/* Add application styles & imports to this file! */
@import 'node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';

.my-table {
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
.my-table table[mat-table] {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.my-table table[mat-table] {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: inherit;
}
.my-table table[mat-table] thead tr {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.my-table table[mat-table] thead tr th {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.my-table table[mat-table] tbody {
  overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
.my-table table[mat-table] tbody tr {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.my-table table[mat-table] tbody tr td {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

html

```
<div class="my-table">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
      The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>No.</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.position }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.name }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Weight</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.weight }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Symbol</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.symbol }}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr
      mat-header-row
      *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"
      style="#A8ACAA"
    ></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cs4gzk?file=src%2Fglobal_styles.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: it worked when I added `::ng-deep` to `.my-table table[mat-table] tbody` and set a height limit.